# Using getframe in Matlab on Windows

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, video-recording

I used the code which I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773127/placing-picture-on-axis-of-matab-figure) but added in the final loop the     `ani(ii)=getframe;` and after the loop 
`movie2avi(ani, 'orbeeit.avi', 'compression', 'None');`. instead of proper `avi` I get a frozen smashed `avi` (length 10 sec) which its only frame is this one [image: one]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16878561/1698972) could help as alternative way for `movie2avi`.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Are you using the exact same code as in the answer to your previous question? If so, can you post a link to the image you're working with?

Comment: @pm89 I tried it but it just opens figure(2) and figure(3) and the output is MYFILE.avi which includes nothing exept grey background.

Comment: @Eitan T I work with peppers.png but I also tried tifs and same result.. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably caused by Windows Vista (and newer) **in conjunction with certain graphics drivers** as described in [***this bug report***](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/384622).

You can change the `renderer` after you created the figure:

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
```

Or

```
opengl('software');
```

Comment: that's an improvment (now the ball moves from the right axis to the left) but the problem continues. I use windows 7 Home premium

Comment: Can you provide more details about the persisting problem?

Comment: Well, in order to show you the problem I uploaded my video to vimeo. surprisingly, it worked fine (without the diagonal line and proper color map).Maybe the problem is with vlc and its codecs. It also worked on xbmc player. So problem is solved after all. thanks.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner No problem. You might be interested in [`implay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/implay.html).