# Matlab videowriter captures black screen

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Matlab videowriter captures a black screen from the figure. How can I use the Matlab figure to wait for the content to load before capturing with videowriter?

Comment: See if [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16885631/1698972) solves anything.

Comment: Weird I already had used zbuffer but with opengl the frames seem to come through again :)